# will many processes be automatically allocated to different processors on a multi-core processor?

Tags: c

I have a puzzle.When a process runs on a multi-core processor, if the process has multiple threads, multiple threads will be automatically allocated to different processors. If the process forks many processes, will they also be automatically allocated to different processors?

Comment: Probably they will. The operating systems takes care of this.

Comment: Different processes are executed in the order determined by the OS scheduler. Which core that executes what and when is nothing the programmer should typically care about.

Answer (score -1):

The allocation of processes may be different between different processors, but, in general (in multi-core processors), each process goes to a different core and they will have 100% of the power of its designated core.

When you have more processes than cores they distribute between the cores they have and the designated processes to the same core will share the power of the it through synchronization of processes.

Comment: I struggle to make sense of this. The OS normally assigns the processes to cores and the can even change the core while the process is running. And normally you don't have 100% of the core available as you have to share it with processes from other applications.

Comment: When you have several processes running on the same core they share its power. Maybe one of these processes has 60% of the power and other have 40% in case there were two of them. These can be modified by synchronization of processes.

Comment: I think what @KamiKaze is saying is that you give the impression that it's the cpu itself that handles the distribution, when the answer is that it is the operating system.